# Calculation to avoid negative value in database

Tags: c#, sql-server

How to set a trap in my program that when I push the purchase button and the quantity to be purchased exceeds the amount remaining on my database it will give an error that there's no enough amount left. Currently it only goes to a negative value. Sql server does not support unsigned values and I do not know if what I want to do is even possible.

Here's my code.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
 @"Data Source=DESKTOP-39SPLT0\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=posDB;Integrated Security=True");

string Query = "UPDATE tblProducts SET qty = qty - @quantity where pName = @name";         
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", int.Parse(txBurger.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", label1.Text);              
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con))
{                
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", int.Parse(txCheese.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", label5.Text);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Why not just query the database for the quantity available and return a message to the user that they chose a quantity higher than what is available, but I'd look into making your UI display the quantity available to prevent the user from selecting more than what is available, or make your UI control have a max of the quantity available...

Comment: @RyanWilson questionable idea - data in DB could be updated by someone else at the same time and end result will be the same. OP should only update row if there is enough quality and fail transaction otherwise

Comment: @RyanWilson The trick to that approach is proper locking such that it's not possible for the value to change after you query it and before you actually apply the update.  Just a regular query before hand, without anything else, wouldn't be good enough.  And the lock couldn't realistically last from when you show the value to the user until you make a change (you can't expect everyone else to be locked out that whole time) so there *will* be a possibility of the user attempting to perform an operation that will end up failing.

Comment: Agree with @RyanWilson you must get the max quantity value, and validate it before to call the ´update´ statement

Comment: "set a trap in my program" O.o!

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci clearly the OP needs General Akbar. :)

Comment: taking all of these into consideration thanks, lastly what is OP? Noob here.

Comment: @Servy I agree, I was eluding to an updating UI, that updates its quantity values every x seconds, or something to that effect. I was just kind of spit balling on some of the UI design ideas, but definitely check the quantity available before allowing the transaction to go through.

Comment: @ChresAbte "OP" = "Original Post"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could set a `CONSTRAINT` on the value of `qty` on the table. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE test (qty int);
ALTER TABLE test ADD CONSTRAINT PosQty CHECK (qty >= 0);
GO

INSERT INTO test VALUES(3);
GO
UPDATE test
SET qty = qty - 2; --Will work (3 - 2 = 1) 
GO
UPDATE test
SET qty = qty - 3; --Will fail (1 - 3 = -2)
GO
UPDATE test
SET qty = qty - 1; --Will work (1 - 1 = 0)
GO
--Clean up
DROP TABLE test;
```

Of course, this may not be suitable, depending on your scenario. you definitely need to ensure you error handle appropriately.

Comment: Thank you! Since I want to be able to update the database down to zero I replaced the constraint 0 to -1 and works like a charm.

Comment: @ChresAbte that seems like a bad idea. `>=` means "Greater than or Equal to" so `qty >= 0` will permit a value of `0`. On the other hand, `qty >= -1` will allow a quantity of `-1`. Use the version I have supplied. If you're looking at my `UPDATE` statements, that's because they are run sequentially. at the point of the statement `UPDATE test SET qty = qty - 3;` `qty` has a value of `1`.  `2 - 3 = -2` which is not `>=0`. I didn't think it would need it, but I've put the (very simple) maths of the statements in there for you.

Comment: tried your version, I have 10 on quantity ordered 10 and the got an error about the constraint but in `qty >= -1` it did go though. It will not allow the value `-1`.

Comment: I'll double check

Comment: @ChresAbte sounds like you've done something else wrong, or the value was less than 10. `10 - 10 = 0 >= 0`. If you run that query I've supplied, and do `SELECT qty FROM test;`  before the `DROP` you'll see that the value of `qty` is 0.

Comment: Ok I take it back I don't know what went wrong at first but your query is right. if I have => -1 it allows a -1 on my database. Thank you for the patience.

Comment: Glad you got there in the end. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do this:

First, change your query:

```
UPDATE tblProducts 
SET qty = qty - @quantity 
where pName = @name
AND qty >= @quantity;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

Then, instead of using `ExecuteNonQuery` use `ExecuteScalar` and check if the number of records modified is `0` it means that the `@quantity` is bigger than the value of `qty`.

Also, I would recommend adding a check constraint as shown in Larnu's [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49387106/3094533)

Comment: thanks, Larnus answer already works jsut changed 0 to -1 so that my database can still be down to zero.

Comment: @ChresAbte Yes, it should work and that's why I've upvoted it. However, combining both our answers you can avoid the exception thrown from the check constraint - and still get an indication if the update actually changed the value of qty.

Comment: Okay I take it back Larnu's >=0 was right. :) super noob here. I'll consider adding your query as well if this will work for me with Larnu's.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use a stored proc call and wrap the whole piece of code into a transaction. The following isn't complete code, but you should be able to take it from here.

```
declare @newQty int
begin tran updateQty

UPDATE tblProducts SET qty = qty - @quantity where pName = @name
select @newQty qty = qty from tblProducts where pName = @name
if (@newQty < 0)
Begin
    rollback tran updateQty
    THROW 51000, 'The quantity is too low', 1;  
END
else 
BEGIN
    commit tran updateQty
END
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it. I see Larnus more accessible to my knowledge this time this is just for a school project but I will consider this later if I'm still going to pursue this course. :)